# How to speed up Android Studio having I3 processor

Tags: android, android-studio

How to speed up Android studio it is opening project at a very slow speed I am using I3 processor or is their any other alternative to it .

Comment: Fairly decent setup: 8 GB RAM, an SSD (which boosts everything a lot) and an i5 processor.

Comment: You should do some searching, there are quite a few posts relating to the subject of speeding it up for slower computers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have 8 GB of RAM, if you don't have 8 GB of RAM, get it extended.Because I was also facing the same issue, but when I extended it to 8 GB, it started working fine.

Second most important thing,don't use intel HAXM for simulation purpose.Use genymotion for simulation. [you can download it from here](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)